# send image php swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send an image on my local PHP server with swift
I don't understand why I have an error message (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

here is my code:

```
var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://http:192.168.1.73:8888/upload.php")!)
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)

request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var body = NSMutableData.alloc()


// Image
body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"htdocs\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData(imageData)
body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



request.HTTPBody = body


var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
println(returnData)
var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

println("returnString \(returnString)")
```

Comment: `"http://http:192.168.1.73:8888/upload.php"` is a invalid URL...

Comment: no when I try it with my browser it says ok.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the unwrapping of an `Optional` value, because it may be `nil` and not a real value.

Take this line for example:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://http:192.168.1.73:8888/upload.php")!)
```

If `NSURL(string:"http://http:192.168.1.73:8888/upload.php")` returns `nil`, you would be calling `NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nil)` which is invalid.

You need to check if the unwrapped value is valid:

```
if let url = NSURL(string:"http://http:192.168.1.73:8888/upload.php") {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
}
```

Comment: sorry but I have the same error. if I put /*var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

println("returnString \(returnString)")*/ I don't have error but I can't save the fille at the URL

Comment: @julienlescoulie Again, you are unwrapping `returnData!` without asking if it is nil. And you are doing the same in several places. You need to fix all of them.

Comment: I tried but I think the real question is: why it returns nil?